# Factory objects creator with generics

Tags: java, generics, factory-pattern

I want to do a factory pattern in java with generics. My code is:

The interface:

```
public abstract class Factory<T> {
    public abstract T create();
}
```

FactoryA class:

```
public class FactoryA extends Factory<FactoryA> {

    public FactoryA() {

    }

    public FactoryA create() {
        return new FactoryA();
    }

}
```

FactoryB class:

```
public class FactoryB extends Factory<FactoryB> {

    public FactoryB() {

    }

    public FactoryB create() {
        return new FactoryB();
    }

}
```

The main class:

```
public class FactoryCreator {

    public static <T> T createFactory() {
        Factory<T> t = ?; // is that right way?
        return t.create();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FactoryA factoryA = FactoryCreator.createFactory();
        FactoryB factoryB = FactoryCreator.createFactory();
    }
}
```

The question, what **Factory t =** need to be equal, or is there any other way?

Comment: There's no way to do this like you're hoping.  You'll need to end up doing `FactoryA factoryA = FactoryA.create()`.

Comment: @louis-wasserman, That's not factory pattern.

Comment: Why do you want to create a class that serves as a factory of its kind? Could it be that you want class FactoryA to serve as factory of class A?

Comment: No, FactoryA and FactoryB are Individually classes

Comment: @phpnuker: `FactoryA` is an instance of the factory pattern.  You're trying to do some kind of factory of factories.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you're trying to achieve, but this might help;

```
public interface Factory<T> 
{
    public T create(String type);
    public T create(String type, Object arg);
    public T create(String type, Object[] args);
}
```

And then have a class implement that factory interface, like this;

```
public class TemplateFactory<T> implements Factory {

    @Override
    public T create(String type) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        return create(type, null);
    }

    @Override
    public T create(String type, Object arg) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        // Convert to array of 1 element
        Object[] arguments = new Object[1];
        arguments[0] = arg;
        return create(type, arguments);
    }

    @Override
    public T create(String type, Object[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        // Create array for all the parameters
        Class<?> params[] = (args != null) ? new Class<?>[args.length] : new Class<?>[0];
        if(args != null)
        {
            // Adding the types of the arguments
            for(int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i)
                params[i] = (args[i] != null) ? args[i].getClass() : null;
        }

        try
        {
            // Create a class variable
            Class classLoader = Class.forName(type);
            // Find the right constructor
            Constructor co;
            if(params.length > 0)
                co = classLoader.getConstructor(params);
            else
                co = classLoader.getConstructor();
            // Instantiate the class with the given arguments
            T newObject = (T)co.newInstance(args);
            return newObject;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this (using some imaginary strategy-classes as an example):

```
TemplateFactory<StrategyInterface> factory;
factory = new TemplateFactory<>();

factory.create("packageName.StrategyA");
factory.create("packageName.StrategyB");
factory.create("packageName.StrategyC");
```

The strategy classes (A, B and C) would implement the StrategyInterface-class in this example.

Comment: It sorta sucks that this is more-or-less the only way to accomplish this (obviously koljaTM's way of providing the actual Class object will also work, even though that means coupling is stronger). Are there no new tricks in Java8 that makes this more...clean?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
public static <T extends Factory> T createFactory(Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        t = clazz.newInstance();
        return t.create();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
...
FactoryA factoryA = FactoryCreator.createFactory(FactoryA.class);
```

alternatively, without parameters. But then you need two methods.

```
public static FactoryA createFactoryA() {
   return new FactoryA().create();
}
...
FactoryA factoryA = FactoryCreator.createFactoryA();
```

Since the Generic types are erased at runtime you have to supply the Class parameter so that the runtime knows what class you are talking about.

Comment: Tried it in Eclipse and it compiles at least ;) Interesting link though, thanks.

Comment: @koljaTM, I know that, but i do not want to give a class type parameter in createFactory method, because the **<T extends Factory>** do this.

Comment: The type parameter only exists at compile time, it is unknown to the runtime.

Comment: @phpnuker what part of comment by LouisWasserman didn't you get clear? This **can't** be achieved in Java. You will need `Class<T>` to make it work.

Comment: @luiggi-mendoza, i just want that one class will can create some objects which needed and if possible without giving parameters into a function.

Comment: @phpnuker one more time: **this can't be possible in Java, you will need to pass an argument like `Class<T> clazz`**

Comment: By your last edit, `FactoryA` will only be able to create instances of itself, making it a useless generic factory.

Comment: That's what it does in the question, I was merely trying to get to the general concept.